# Bot Framework dialog with several bots

Tags: c#, botframework

Using Bot Framework, I'm trying to make 2 bots communicate. Here is my scenario. I got 2 bots :

- Bot A : a general bot plugged to LUIS
- Bot B : a specialized bot based on LUIS intents

User can talk to each bot.

This is what I am trying to do :
In a dialog in Bot A, Bot A calls LUIS, gets the intents and then calls a business method of Bot B exposed via REST.

**Bot A**

Entry point :

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

RootDialog :

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        var intents = await GetIntents(activity); // get the intents from LUIS

        var result = await GetBusinessOperation(activity, intents); // call a WebAPI which call method PerformResponse from Bot B according to the LUIS intent

        await context.PostAsync(result); // return our reply to the user

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}
```

**Bot B**

In Bot B, I want to create a new dialog to interact with the user. Bot B got the `Activity` object from Bot A via the REST API.

```
 [Authorize]
    public async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostPerformResponse([FromBody]Model model)
    {
        Activity activity = model.Activity;

        MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(activity.ServiceUrl);

        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new BusinessDialog()); // This creates a new dialog but it will not be linked to the dialog created in Bot A. This results in an error 412 when the framework try to do SetBotData() at the end of dialog in Bot A

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

From my understanding, to create a new dialog I need to call :

```
context.Call(new BusinessDialog(), this.CallbackMethod);
```

or

```
context.Forward(new BusinessDialog(), this.CallbackMethod, activity, CancellationToken.None);
```

The problem is the `IDialogContext context` object is not serializable and can't be sent from Bot A to Bot B via a REST call.

In Bot B, I can create an initial dialog like I did in Bot A. It works fine but I have an error 412 at the end of dialog of Bot A when the framework call automatically the method `setBotData()`. I believe it is because the dialog in Bot B is not created using `context.Call()` or `context.Forward()`.

Do you have any ideas how I can have access to the `IDialogContext context` in Bot B or any ideas about managing dialogs between bots ?

Regards

Comment: Please provide more code mate

Comment: I am not sure that your approach is the best one. Why are you splitting your logic in 2 bots? Why do you want that Bot B interacts with the user? You will cause a huge mess in the context / conversations!

Comment: This is the client's demand. Having several specialized bots in the same environment, so they can interact with each other. We factorize the global comportment in a general bot (Bot A). What we want to do is : when Bot A needs an information that Bot B has, Bot A asks Bot B for it. That process should be invisible for the user.

Comment: Does the client knows how the bot framework works? Probably not. Here it seems that your "bot" B should be an API, not really a bot if you don't want to create a huge mess

Comment: You should implement your own IBotDataStore<BotData> https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure has examples in DocumentDb and Azure Table Storage.  Another thing to consider is that you can have multiple bots in a single BotBuilder web application using MultiCredentialProvider: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2258#issuecomment-280506334