# Microsoft Chat BOT with multiple BOTs integration

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I am working on a requirement where we need to create a chat BOT application using Azure BOT service that takes input from the user and based on the response from the user, redirect the user to the chat bot of the particular department.

I would like some suggestions or recommendations on how this can be achieved.

Comment: We are developing the application top of bot framework and deployed in azure bot framework. so there is a channel configuration or we can run bot on different medium like fb,slack,team. As per your request it is connecting to different bot and I am not understanding why we are connecting different bot based on the question ? instead of you can use single bot ?

Comment: Updated the question : I am working on a requirement where we need to create a chat BOT application using Azure BOT service that takes input from the user and based on the response from the user, redirect the user to the chat bot of the particular department.

I would like some suggestions or recommendations on how this can be achieved.

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth - Our requirement has each department having individual BOT. We need to create one parent BOT that takes input from user and redirects to the specific department's BOT based on user input.

Comment: Ok, got It! are you planning to integrate any thrid party channels like ms-teams,etc or your own ui ?

Comment: check eric comment - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864823/bot-framework-dialog-with-several-bots

Comment: We thought about using teams channel or using an iframe for our own UI. But firstly it would be Iframe for POC. So, any ideas how to redirect to specific BOTs based on user input

Comment: I don't think redirection is a good practice instead of that selection of depart menu you can display the respective answer from qna maker. So this way you can reduce multiple bot creation and cost.

Comment: from the link you have shared( eric comment) we see that they are redirecting to respective BOT using user credentials. But , our case, multiple BOTs are already existing for various departments and we need to create a parent BOT that needs to redirect to individual BOTS based on user input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232641/discussion-between-sharvani-and-rajeeshmenoth).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable communication between 2 BOTs using Azure BOT service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67620958/how-to-enable-communication-between-2-bots-using-azure-bot-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is through Bot Framework Skills. You can check for more information on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/skills-conceptual?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: Thank you for this. I have integrated 2 BOTs as in the documentation given but when I am trying to run the code in the emulator, I am getting "Cannot post activity. Unauthorized.
POST401directline/conversations/<conversationId>/activities" error. I have given AppId and passwords as well as per instructions. Could you please help me here.

Comment: its working now...thanks a lot...had wrongly placed the Microsoft app id.