# How to enable communication between 2 BOTs using Azure BOT service?

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-bot-service

Our requirement has each department having individual BOTs. We need to create one parent BOT that takes input from user and redirects to the specific department's BOT based on user input. For this, we need to know how to communicate between 2 different BOTs. Can anyone help me here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Chat BOT with multiple BOTs integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67617581/microsoft-chat-bot-with-multiple-bots-integration)

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: I have used microsoft skill bot and it worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Microsoft Chat BOT with multiple BOTs integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67617581/microsoft-chat-bot-with-multiple-bots-integration/67621629#67621629)

> The way to do this is through Bot Framework Skills. You can check for more information on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/skills-conceptual?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Answer (score 0):

[Direct Line API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-directline?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) enables you to communicate between bots, here's an [example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLine-DotNet/tree/master/samples/core-DirectLine).

Comment: Yes, but that is for calling BOT from HTTP client. I have used microsoft skill bot and it worked for me.